# java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Direct buffer memory with grpc client in spring-boot

Tags: java, grpc-java

Using following libraries:

```
grpc-java : v1.30.2
netty : v4.1.65.Final
JDK : 11
```

I have spring-boot application which acts as grpc client. My application is connected to more than 100 servers in non-secure mode. It is bidirectional stream where server is sending data on regular interval. So I am creating ManagedChannel for each server and processing the received data.

I am using following to create ManagedChannel and passing custom executor while creating Managed channel

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("CustomExecutor")
private ExecutorService customExecutor;

final NettyChannelBuilder channelBuilder = NettyChannelBuilder.forAddress(inetAddr, port).executor(customExecutor);
ManagedChannel managedChannel = channelBuilder.usePlaintext().build();
```

Custom executor is as following:

```
@Bean(name = "CustomExecutor")
public ExecutorService customExecutor() {
        final int maxPoolSize = Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors() * 2;
        return new CustomThreadPoolExecutor(0, maxPoolSize, 60, new ThreadFactoryBuilder().setNameFormat("Custom-%d").build());
}

private class CustomThreadPoolExecutor extends ThreadPoolExecutor {

        public CustomThreadPoolExecutor(final int corePoolSize, final int maximumPoolSize,
                                             final long keepAliveTimeInSeconds,
                                             final ThreadFactory threadFactory) {
            super(corePoolSize, maximumPoolSize, keepAliveTimeInSeconds, TimeUnit.SECONDS,
                    new SynchronousQueue<Runnable>(), threadFactory, new CustomDiscardPolicy());
        }
}

private class CustomDiscardPolicy implements RejectedExecutionHandler {

        @Override
        public void rejectedExecution(Runnable r, ThreadPoolExecutor executor) {
            // log rejection message and further processing.
        }
}
```

Once application started, I observed that after couple of hours, I am getting following errors in my ResponseObserver.

```
io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: UNKNOWN
        at io.grpc.Status.asRuntimeException(Status.java:533)
        at io.grpc.stub.ClientCalls$StreamObserverToCallListenerAdapter.onClose(ClientCalls.java:460)
        at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl.closeObserver(ClientCallImpl.java:426)
        at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl.access$500(ClientCallImpl.java:66)
        at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl$ClientStreamListenerImpl.close(ClientCallImpl.java:689)
        at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl$ClientStreamListenerImpl.access$900(ClientCallImpl.java:577)
        at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl$ClientStreamListenerImpl$1StreamClosed.runInternal(ClientCallImpl.java:751)
        at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl$ClientStreamListenerImpl$1StreamClosed.runInContext(ClientCallImpl.java:740)
        at io.grpc.internal.ContextRunnable.run(ContextRunnable.java:37)
        at io.grpc.internal.SerializingExecutor.run(SerializingExecutor.java:123)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Direct buffer memory
        at java.base/java.nio.Bits.reserveMemory(Bits.java:175)
        at java.base/java.nio.DirectByteBuffer.<init>(DirectByteBuffer.java:118)
        at java.base/java.nio.ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(ByteBuffer.java:317)
        at io.netty.buffer.PoolArena$DirectArena.allocateDirect(PoolArena.java:632)
        at io.netty.buffer.PoolArena$DirectArena.newChunk(PoolArena.java:607)
        at io.netty.buffer.PoolArena.allocateNormal(PoolArena.java:202)
        at io.netty.buffer.PoolArena.tcacheAllocateSmall(PoolArena.java:172)
        at io.netty.buffer.PoolArena.allocate(PoolArena.java:134)
        at io.netty.buffer.PoolArena.allocate(PoolArena.java:126)
        at io.netty.buffer.PooledByteBufAllocator.newDirectBuffer(PooledByteBufAllocator.java:395)
        at io.netty.buffer.AbstractByteBufAllocator.directBuffer(AbstractByteBufAllocator.java:187)
        at io.netty.buffer.AbstractByteBufAllocator.directBuffer(AbstractByteBufAllocator.java:178)
        at io.netty.channel.unix.PreferredDirectByteBufAllocator.ioBuffer(PreferredDirectByteBufAllocator.java:53)
        at io.netty.channel.DefaultMaxMessagesRecvByteBufAllocator$MaxMessageHandle.allocate(DefaultMaxMessagesRecvByteBufAllocator.java:114)
        at io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollRecvByteAllocatorHandle.allocate(EpollRecvByteAllocatorHandle.java:75)
        at io.netty.channel.epoll.AbstractEpollStreamChannel$EpollStreamUnsafe.epollInReady(AbstractEpollStreamChannel.java:780)
        at io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop.processReady(EpollEventLoop.java:480)
        at io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop.run(EpollEventLoop.java:378)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:989)
        at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
        ... 1 common frames omitted
```

As it is not OOM for heap space, so heap dump is not generated.

I see https://github.com/grpc/grpc-java/issues/6910 which is marked as CLOSED.

Is this a known issue or am I missing anything here?

Comment: > grpc-java : v1.30.2



Can you move to the latest version of grpc-java i.e. 1.40.0 and try to reproduce?

Answer (score 1):

You message chunks may be too small.  In my case I had a setting which adjusts how many bytes there are per chunk.  I wanted to check that chunking occurs correctly so I set it to a low amount in my case 30 bytes.  So it worked correctly with a single chunked entry.

However, when I tried to batch a whole table of over 3000+ entries, I got an out of memory error.  There's an [implementation detail about `onNext` enqueueing the data](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-java/issues/7584#issuecomment-720733919), which means that onNext immediately returns, but the transmission may not have started yet.

So what happened what I just filled up my direct buffer memory space which is 64MB by default (you can increase it by adding `-XX:MaxDirectMemorySize=512m`).  When I set it to something more reasonable like 1MB it worked correctly again and there's no out of memory.