# How do I limit the GRPC send queue?

Tags: java, grpc

When you perform onNext() on a stream response in GRPC it queues it up for transmission, this allocates on direct buffer memory rather than heap as such `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Direct buffer memory` will not generate a useful heap dump.  This can be simulated by creating a

```
message Chunk {
  bytes data = 1
}
```

And [sending multiple small chunks into a stream where the receiving end may not be as quick](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70996195/242042) will cause this to trigger.  The proper fix would be to make sure the server does not do anything stupid like send many small chunks, but this still can be a vector of DoS attack that could shut down a service.

My question is in GRPC, is there a setting on the server side to limit the amount and block further onNext until the queue is diminished, with a timeout to cancel the operation when the transfer takes too long?  That way it won't shutdown the service but just the GRPC call.

I am thinking the answer would somewhere be in this [Github issue](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-java/issues/2247) though it seems a lot of code for something so fundamental.

Answer (score 1):

The local send buffer size on the server is hard-coded to [32 KB](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-java/blob/431fb0255fbed3f46ff3aca15ab37273c6143a47/core/src/main/java/io/grpc/internal/AbstractStream.java#L118). You can use the `ServerCallStreamObserver.isReady()` or the `onReadyHandler` to block to achieve flow control (and also timeout for how long you wait).

Comment: so it needs to go down to the netty level in order to make the necessary change and there's no higher level API on GRPC itself?

Comment: Using `NettyServerBuilder` is "not going down to netty level" . It is a gRPC API which can be directly used instead of using `ServerBuilder`

Comment: The flow control window controls how soon data is sent, but not the local queuing. The local queuing, above which `onReady() == false`, is hard-coded to 32 KB. https://github.com/grpc/grpc-java/blob/431fb0255fbed3f46ff3aca15ab37273c6143a47/core/src/main/java/io/grpc/internal/AbstractStream.java#L118

Comment: I just checked, the flow control window is in bytes and defaults to 1MB.  So I am not sure if this is what is used to prevent GRPC from using up all the direct memory.